# Track flash errors using javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, error-handling

Is it possible to catch flash errors with javascript. Currently I am catching and sending all global errors to my server for tracking and I'd like to be able to track flash errors too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to catch the error within your flash app, you can call a javascript function using ExternalInterface.

in AS3:

```
ExternalInterface.call("sendToJavaScript", someData);
```

in js:

```
function sendToJavaScript(data){
    console.log(data); // prints someData from flash app
}
```

See this Class Reference page for implementation details: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html